# How to configure PHP CLI on linux ubuntu to run as www-data?

Tags: linux, php, permissions, command-line-interface, file-permissions

I have a symfony2 application on my ubuntu. Symfony has a plenty of useful console commands  (like `php app/console cache:clear` or `php app/console assets:install web`).

The problem is If I run them as `root` user the newly generated files will have `root:root` user/group, and if I acces my website I get errors (becouse apache cannot read/modify these files -> they should have `www-data:www-data`).

Running `chown www-data:www-data` solves the problem, but running it every time I clear my cache is not a solution.

#### How can I configure PHP CLI to always run as www-data user/group?

or

#### How can I run a command as a diffrent user (being root, run it as www-data)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Run a command as another user once:

```
sudo -u www-data php script.php
```

This should work if you have `sudo` installed and are `root` (or another user that is allowed to do that; see the `sudo` group, `man sudoers` and `visudo`).

**For reusability, add an alias.** Place this in your `.bashrc`, `.profile` or similar (and reload the shell to make it effective):

```
alias phpwww='sudo -u www-data php'
```

You can then type `phpwww script.php` and it will actually execute `sudo -u www-data php script.php` for you.

---

For other, more complex and error-prone ways, read on.

As for always running php as `www-data`, there are several possiblities. You could create a simple wrapper shellscript. If `/usr/bin/php` is only a soft-link to `/usr/bin/php5` or similar, that makes it simpler. Just replace the soft-link (NOT the file `php5`) with a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo -u www-data php5 $*

return $?
```

That's not tested though. Also be aware that this will ALWAYS try to run `php5` as user `www-data`, even if the user may not be `root` and may not have permission to do so. And it may also not be what you really want. Some installed services may run into problems when trying to execute php.

A (possibly better) solution to only apply that to root may be to leave the soft-link `/usr/bin/php` alone and place the script in `/root/bin` instead. Then add that folder to PATH via `.bashrc`, `.profile` or similar. If you have `/etc/skel/.profile`, that may point out how that is done:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Once this is in your `.bashrc`, `.profile` or similar, every new shell you open will allow you to directly execute any executables (+x) in `$HOME/bin` (`/root/bin` for root).

Hint: You may want to name the wrapper script something like `phpwww` so you explicitly specify `php script.php` or `phpwww script.php` to decide if you want regular or sudo'ed php.

Comment: Funny, half a hear has passed and I stumbled upon my own question again =) Seems like I forgot to accept your answer last time - I just fixed that, thank you!

Comment: The alias method makes so much bloody sense, and it solved my exact problem

Answer (score 1):

### Answered by mwargh on ##linux (IRC Freenode.net)

---

To run a commands as a diffrent user -> switch to that user useing:

```
su www-data
```

---

I'd still be interested (if its possible) in configuring PHP so that running:

```
root@mycomp php (php script creating a file)
```

as **root** user

will result in creating a file with **www-data:www-data** user/group

(this way i would not have to switch from root to www-data to run my commands)

Answer (score 1):

I would try making /usr/bin/php owned by www-data and set the suid permission, which forces the command to be executed by the file owner.  You'd do this with:

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/php
```

of you like the octal notation:

```
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/php
```

Though I must say it should make one uneasy whenever you are making www-data the owner of anything, as the point of the www-data account is to own as little as possible.

Comment: Which is why I'll go with riha's answer

Answer (score 1):

if you got the php-fpm (FastCGI Process Manager)
 you can set it up in the config file located at (atleast for centos): `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`
 at line 39 you can set the user and 49 you set the group

Comment: That doesn't apply to `php-cli`, does it?

Answer (score 1):

create script file:

```
touch /usr/bin/phpuid
chmod +x /usr/bin/phpuid
```

add content:

```
#!/bin/bash

UIDX="#"`stat -c '%u' $1`
sudo -u $UIDX php5 $*
```

run your scripts from root:

```
phpuid /path/to/script.php
```

or use interpreter in your scripts

```
#!/usr/bin/phpuid
<?php
phpinfo();
```

note: 
tested on debian 7 
you might require to install sudo

```
apt-get install sudo
```

all files created by script.php will have the same uid of that script