# permission issue with "user:hostings" and "nginx:nginx"

Tags: centos, permissions

I have centos 7 installed with nginx on a dedicated machine, running symfony (PHP) applications. Every site has its own user, in this example let's say its "`user`" in the "`hostings`" group. Application required console commands run like

```
$ php bin/console cache:clear
```

In this case the application's folder **/var/cache** will be created with "`user:hostings`" owner.

The problem is, when a visitor arrived on the site (nginx / webserver runs the application), it usually creates some additional files too in the same **/var/cache** directory, with "`nginx:nginx`" ownership.

So if one of the files are can't write with another's permission, it generates server 500 error.

What is the best scenario here? Should I change "`nginx`" user's group to "`hostings`" or "`user:hostings`" to "`user:nginx`" ? Or something else here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your best bet is to run the PHP commands with user nginx in order for the directory to be created with nginx:nginx owner. The other option is to start the nginx service with user nginx but group hostings. Maybe you should take a look at [How to configure PHP CLI on linux ubuntu to run as www-data?](https://serverfault.com/questions/453811/how-to-configure-php-cli-on-linux-ubuntu-to-run-as-www-data)